# Mobile website - component caching limit for Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, iphone, browser-cache

I'm developing a website primarily for use on mobile phones. One of our guys here has an older iPhone, and he is the only one who experiences a "slowness of the site sometimes" (Wow. much specifics).
So I'm looking into it and I found these blog entries where it is stated that the iPhone does not cache individual components  above 25kb (EDIT: reduced now to 15kb).
But these are a few years old.

[yuiblog](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/06/28/mobile-browser-cache-limits/) - [phpied](http://www.phpied.com/iphone-caching/) - [guypo](http://www.guypo.com/uncategorized/mobile-browser-cache-sizes-round-2/)

I'm thinking that his iPhone is downloading the images and scripts again.
Does anybody know what is the size limit for caching individual components on the iPhone and on Android?